# Custom Transformation Per Row Using Polars

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, user-defined-functions, python-polars

I have a dataset with a working solution that uses a for loop with Polars. However, I would like to use a built in Polars function like map_elements to apply a function that creates a struct of variable length based on an id column.

Working Solution:

```
import polars as pl
pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(1000)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 2, 3],
    "dog": ["labrador", "labrador", "boxer", "airedale"],
    "age": [2, 2, 3, 4],
    "owner": ["Jim", "Paul", "Kim", "Lynne"],
    "spots": [None, None, True, None],
    "food": ["Raw", "Kibble", None, "Raw"],
    "leash": [True, False, None, True]
})

id_struct_dict = {
    1: ["owner", "food"],
    2: ["owner", "spots", "food"],
    3: ["owner", "food", "leash"]
}

run = 0
for id, lst in id_struct_dict.items():
    print(id)
    struct_expr = pl.struct(lst).map_elements(lambda x: str(x)).alias("struct")
    if run == 0:
        df = df.with_columns([pl.when(pl.col("id") == id).then(struct_expr).otherwise(None)])
        run += 1
    else:
        df = df.with_columns([pl.when(pl.col("id") == id).then(struct_expr).otherwise(pl.col('struct'))])

df
```

I really dislike my solution, but it is the only way I was able to achieve my desired result. I tried mapping a function/udf via a different method, but the final struct case would apply to all rows despite the difference in ID.

Any ideas/help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple when/then expressions to [`pl.coalesce`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars.coalesce) in order to produce a single column result.

It is possible to "stringify" structs with [`.struct.json_encode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.json_encode.html#polars.Expr.struct.json_encode) if JSON is acceptable.

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.coalesce(
      pl.when(pl.col("id") == _id)
        .then(pl.struct(cols).struct.json_encode())
      for _id, cols in id_struct_dict.items()
   )
   .alias("struct")
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 8)
┌─────┬──────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ dog      ┆ age ┆ owner ┆ spots ┆ food   ┆ leash ┆ struct                                      │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---                                         │
│ i64 ┆ str      ┆ i64 ┆ str   ┆ bool  ┆ str    ┆ bool  ┆ str                                         │
╞═════╪══════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ labrador ┆ 2   ┆ Jim   ┆ null  ┆ Raw    ┆ true  ┆ {"owner":"Jim","food":"Raw"}                │
│ 1   ┆ labrador ┆ 2   ┆ Paul  ┆ null  ┆ Kibble ┆ false ┆ {"owner":"Paul","food":"Kibble"}            │
│ 2   ┆ boxer    ┆ 3   ┆ Kim   ┆ true  ┆ null   ┆ null  ┆ {"owner":"Kim","spots":true,"food":null}    │
│ 3   ┆ airedale ┆ 4   ┆ Lynne ┆ null  ┆ Raw    ┆ true  ┆ {"owner":"Lynne","food":"Raw","leash":true} │
└─────┴──────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @jqurious While this solution significantly improves upon my original approach, it encounters bottlenecks with the for loop and JSON encoding, and it crashed when tested against dummy data (50 columns by 10 million rows). I developed a much faster alternative, which, regrettably, still incorporates a for loop. I iterate over the id_struct_dict, filter the DataFrame for each ID, perform my transformation, and assign the ID to a new df var, which I then append to a list of DataFrames. After completing the for loop, I vertically concat all the DFs together (~3 secs).

Comment: @JasonP Ah, interesting. Perhaps a failing test case for the crash could be created for the Polars team to look at. Can you post the code for this alternative approach maybe?